# NFTables: is it possible to forward traffic without masquerading it?

Tags: smtp, port-forwarding, ip-forwarding, nftables, masquerade

I have a remote server (B) that forwards certain incoming traffic to another port of a different server (A, dest).
With "masquerade" I only see traffic coming from the forward server (B), is it possible to see traffic coming from the original sources (C)? If I replace "masquerade" with "accept" I can't reach anymore port 8080 of destination (A).

Sketch:

```sh
C -> B:25 -> A:8080
# A receives C requests as if B made them
# Unfortunately this breaks some implementations like SPF
```

NFTables configuration:

```
# define destination address
define dest = 10.0.0.2

# table for smtp forwarding
table ip smtp {
 chain pre {
  type nat hook prerouting priority -100
  tcp dport 25 dnat to $dest:8080
 }
 chain post {
  type nat hook postrouting priority 100
  ip daddr $dest masquerade
 }
}
```

Comment: That's just "routing", not forwarding. A firewall only needs to allow such traffic.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you please provide  a minimal working example?

Comment: If the server is a *router in the path* between source and destination it's possible. The fact that it doesn't work probably tells it's no such router.

Comment: Next time it would be easier if you name your server like Server A and Server B or something ;-)
In gernal think about rephrasing your question, I am not 100% if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: @Kound I added a little sketch and server names

Comment: hmm okay, looks like my suggested solution could be an answer. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tero Kilkanen](https://serverfault.com/users/210570/tero-kilkanen) was so nice to answer [my question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035544/using-nftables-to-forward-https-traffic-to-vm-guest-without-masquerade/), i can provide you hopefully with an minimal working example.

Preconditions:

1. IP forward has to be activated (check with `sysctl -a | grep forward`) on `remote server`
2. both server must be in the same network
3. Your `different server` must have the `remote server` as default gateway (Is this possible in your case?)
4. Kernel should be 4.18 otherwise you need to also define a postrouting rule (see [nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)))
5. Your External interface of the `remote server` is `enp35s0` otherwise replace accordingly

Given this you can use the following NFTables rules

```
table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
                iif "enp35s0" tcp dport 25 dnat to 10.0.0.2:8080
        }
}
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

To debug check tcpdump on the `different server`